# Colon placement in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between:

1. `abc:`
2. `:xyz`
3. `abc::xyz`
4. `abc: :xyz`
5. `abc: xyz`
6. `:abc => xyz`

Comment: I gather that 1) is in the context of a hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) `abc:`  it can't exist independently

2) `:xyz`  it is a symbol

```
:xyz.class
 => Symbol
```

3) `abc::xyz`  it represents namespace

Example code:

```
module ABC
    class Xyz
       def initialize
         @size = 400
       end
    end
end

x = ABC::Xyz.new
```

4) `abc: :xyz`

```
hash = {abc: :xyz} #hash key and value all are symbol.
```

5) `abc: xyz`

```
xyz = "just a test"
hash = {abc: xyz} #hash key is symbol, value is string.
```

6) `:abc => xyz`

```
xyz = "just a test"
hash = {:abc => xyz} # same with (5)， just another representation
```

7)  ternary operator `:`

```
abc = 1
xyz = 2
result = abc > xyz ? abc : xyz
=> result = 2
```

Comment: `abc: xyz` is different from `abc: "xyz"`;
`xyz` in `abs: xyz` should be a variable named "xyz"

Comment: yes, you are right，I should describe more clearly and precise.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can't use `abc:` alone. See 4) for reason.

2) `:xyz` is a **symbol** literal. It's very similar to "xyz", except that `:xyz` is immutable, while "xyz" is mutable, and there is always only one `:xyz` in the memory (maybe this is no longer true because Ruby 2.2 introduces symbol GC?)

```
:xyz.class  #=> Symbol
:xyz.to_s  #=> "xyz"
"xyz".to_sym  #=> :xyz
a = :xyz
b = :xyz
a.object_id == b.object_id  #=> true
```

3) `abc::xyz` is rarely be seen, but `Abc::Xyz` is very common. That's the way you refer to the inner class/module/constant `Xyz` of class/module `Abc`. `::` can but should not be used to call class/module methods.

If you really want to see the possible usage of `abc::xyz`, well

```
abc = Module.new do
  def self.xyz; end
end
abc::xyz  # Call the module method xyz of the anonymous module.
```

4) Before Ruby 2.0 `abc: :xyz` can only appear as arguments passed to method calls. As an argument, this is a hash or part of a hash. The following 4 expressions are the same:

```
p abc: :xyz, foo: :bar  #=> prints {:abc => :xyz, :foo => :bar}
p(abc: :xyz, foo: :bar)  #=> prints {:abc => :xyz, :foo => :bar}
p({abc: :xyz, foo: :bar})  #=> prints {:abc => :xyz, :foo => :bar}
p({:abc => :xyz, :foo => :bar})  #=> prints {:abc => :xyz, :foo => :bar}
```

As arguments, the curly braces of hashes can be omitted. And when the keys of a hash are symbols, the colon can be moved behind the symbol, and the fat arrow `=>` can be omitted. This makes hashes look more like JSON objects.

4.1) Ruby 2.0 introduces **keyword arguments**, and `abc: :xyz` can appear as a parameter `abc` with default value `:xyz`

```
def my_method(abc: :xyz)
  puts abc
end
```

5) Well, its just the same as 4), except that the value of the hash is a local variable or a method call

6) The same as 5)

7) Ternary operator

```
x = true ? 1 : 0
```